# Extention of Times operation causes bug in Expand?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, core-language

I have the following code in Mathematica 11.01 :

```
var = (j11^2 + 2 j12^2 + 2 j13^2 + 2 j14^2 + 2 j15^2 + 2 j16^2 + 
    j22^2 + 2 j23^2 + 2 j24^2 + 2 j25^2 + 2 j26^2 + j33^2 + 2 j34^2 + 
    2 j35^2 + 2 j36^2 + j44^2 + 2 j45^2 + 2 j46^2 + j55^2 + 2 j56^2)^2;
Expand[var]
```

This works fine. It's followed by:

```
Unprotect[Times];
Times[label[t1_, l1_String], label[t2_, l2_String]] :=  label[TensorProduct[t1, t2], StringJoin[l1, l2]];
Times[a_, label[t1_, l1_String]] := label[Times[t1, a], l1];
Times[label[t1_, l1_String], a_] := label[Times[t1, a], l1];
```

This is meant to "teach" the `Times` operator to work with "labeled" tensors, sort of like Ricci notation. I've used it extensively before without encountering problems.

However, running `Expand[var]` again after this definition goes into what seems to be an infinite loop.

---

Expansion still works for other similar variables, but it seems as if I've stumbled into an unlucky edge case. My extension of `Times` should not affect the evaluation of `Expand[var]` , as the `label` patterns don't appear in `var`.

With a simpler expression such as:

```
var = (j11^2 + 2 j12^2 + 2 j13^2 + 2 j14^2 + 2 j15^2 + 2 j16^2 +  j22^2 + 2 j56^2)^2;
```

the expansion works fine both before and after my `Times` definition, so I'm not exactly sure what causes the bug.

I would appreciate any help in reproducing the bug, explaining its cause, or seeing if it occurs in other versions of Mathematica.

Comment: Do not use the [tag:bugs] tag until other people have confirmed that the behavior you see is a bug. That being said, "teaching" `Times[]` (and in general basic operators like arithmetic ones) the way you did is **almost never** going to end well. It's better to use `TagSetDelayed[]` instead, and associate multiplication rules with your custom object `label`, e.g. `label /: Times[label[t1_, l1_String], a_] := label[Times[t1, a], l1]`.

Comment: Whatever it was, changing the rule as you specified solves it. I wasn't even aware you could associate rules and patterns to arguments. In FP you learn that a function or a macro acts on its arguments, not on its context or the functions for which it is an argument. This is new to me.